# How to perform Bicubic Interpolation when not all neighbours are known?

Tags: math, image-processing, interpolation, bicubic

[image]

Given only 4 edge values boxed in red, if I want to find out value at f(1,2) and it's nearest 16 neighbours(not sure if itself can be included?) are show in the picture, can I assign 0 values to the unknown functions and perform bicubic interpolation to derive f(1,2)?

Subsequently, with f(1,2) value derived from above, I'd use it's value in addition to the known values to calculate other unknown values.

Is my concept wrong? Can someone teach me if I'm wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your substitute 0 for your unknown values you'll end up with all values ridiculously close to zero. Don't substitute anything for the unknowns, use only the actually known values to fill in the rest.

For the filling in of the pixels, bicubic interpolation should work just fine even though you don't know all the neighbours. There is just less information. The wikipedia articles about [resampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_%28bitmap%29) and [bicubic interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation) are good starting points. If you are looking for actual implementations, try the [OpenCV cvResize function](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/geometric_image_transformations.html#resize).

Comment: thanks, I've to write my own implementation of bicubic interpolation. Wikipedia's bicubic interpolation makes use of matrix to solve which i find hard to implement. I'm trying to implement based off the method which I've found on this http://www.fho-emden.de/~hoffmann/bicubic03042002.pdf, page 8.  Do you happen to be familiar with bicubic interpolation, I've some concepts to clarify if you could help. Thanks!

Comment: In most bicubic examples such as that in the pdf, an intermediate point say f(1.5,1.5) is to be calculated. By truncation, it's nearest neighbor would be f(1,1) and a dx and dy value of 0.5 is calculated. However, in my example, the point happen to be f(1,1) itself and the its nearest neighbor is itself, does it mean the dx and dy value is 0?

Comment: No, you should label the red points in your diagram as f(1,1) f(1,2) f(2,1) and f(2,2) you need the additional 12 surrounding points with values at f(0,0) ... f(4,4) to perform bicubic interpolation. your blue point is "off grid" so to speak, just like the circle op page 8 of your pdf, and dx and dy are both 1/3. So your blue point is at f(1+1/3,1+1/3)

Comment: So does it mean my example is wrong and that bicubic interpolation cannot be used to derive a non integer point such as the blue point in my example given its surrounding neighbours are f(0,0)...f(4,4) because dx and dy is missing? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It has nothing to do with missing dx and dy. Your example is just stated wrong for bicubic interpolation. You need 16 known surrounding points to perform bicubic interpolation. In your case, with only 4 known surrounding points, you should look into other techniques. But I assume you are interpolating a larger image? Not just an image of 4 pixels? In that case you just need to include more pixels from the source image.

Comment: yes, I'm interpolating a larger image. Stackoverflow doesn't want to me to have extended discussion in comment. You've been a great help. Thanks a lot.